# Remove a nested element from a JSON Array using GSON in Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I am calling a REST service and getting a JSON response and storing it. However, I do not need all the fields in the JSON response. I was wondering if there was anyway I can remove an element from a JSON Array using GSON in Java.

For example, let's say I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "array": [{
            "text": "hello world",
            "test": {
                "Testing": "testing"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I drop the field "text" from the JSON array? I have looked around but could not find anything specific to using GSON (which is what I am using for parsing the JSON and adding customized elements as well). I have tried "data.getAsJsonArray("array").remove(0);" but it removes everything in my array.

Comment: `data.getAsJsonArray("array").get(0).remove("text")` Your array contains objects, which themselves have a `text` property. You need to access the object rather than remove it, and remove its property. (you may need to cast the result of the `array.get(0)` to `JsonObject` as the `.get(i)` returns a `JsonElement` which doesn't define `.remove()`)

Comment: Your reply helped me! Got it to work. data.getAsJsonArray("array").get(0).getAsJsonObject().remove("text"); Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is not a GSON solution for the problem, I would use a JSONPath library for this problem.

If you use Maven you can import the libraries with:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can simply use the JSONPath library to remove the property:

```
try (InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("replaceExample.json")) {
    String json = new Scanner(in).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
    DocumentContext dc = JsonPath.parse(json).delete("$..text");
    System.out.println(dc.jsonString());
}
```

Assuming that `replaceExample.json` contains your question JSON, this prints out:

```
{"array":[{"test":{"Testing":"testing"}}]}
```